# mp4 video not playing

Tags: html, html5-video

Trying to access my video (mp4, h.264, AAC ) with browsers like:
www.mysitesample.com/video.mp4.
It is displayed well in Safari and Opera (OSX) but on Firefox I have "file is corrupt " error. On Chrome player is being loaded but cannot press play. 
The file seems to be fine, I can open it in also on my computer. 
Also have other video which works in every browser (mp4, h.264, aac).
These 2 videos seem to be in the same format and codecs so im not sure why one is not working in Firefox and Chrome ? what can cause this problem?

Comment: could you post a link to this file?

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't,  it is private. Is it a way I can check what is wrong with this file? In OSX when I press getInfo I have only info about: codecs, duration, audio chanels

Comment: try uploading the file again or converting the webm to an mp4 online to get a new file

Comment: It would have been a way for us to test on our machines and to check what's wrong. To get correct info about a video file, I like to use vlc, Open Network, video infos. Also, you can check the  developer tools, Network, to see how the browser downloaded it.

Comment: in Developer tool I have content type for this file: Content-Type:video/mp4. So it should be ok

Comment: In VLC i've checked that the only difference is that in the video that is not working first stream is Video, second Audio and in the working video first stream is Audio. Can it be the issue here?